# C++ SFML Displaying Multiple Images

Tags: c++, image, animation, textures, sfml

I am trying to make a program so that it displays an image of a skull with it's mouth open and then closes with 1 second intervals in-between. When I run it, it only displays the "skullmouthopen". I am not sure where I have gone wrong, I do not get any error messages. Just a little virus prank for my friend :)

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
using namespace sf;

void f()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
}


int main()
{
    RenderWindow gameDisplay(VideoMode(800, 600), "Oops");

    while (gameDisplay.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;
        while (gameDisplay.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
                gameDisplay.close();
        }

        Texture texture;
        if (!texture.loadFromFile("o_cdf78ec6b8037e00-0.png"))
        {
            // error...
        }

        Texture texture2;
        if (!texture.loadFromFile("o_cdf78ec6b8037e00-1.png"))
        {
            // error...
        }

        sf::Sprite skullmouthclosed;
        skullmouthclosed.setTexture(texture);
        skullmouthclosed.setPosition(300, 200);

        Sprite skullmouthopen;
        skullmouthopen.setTexture(texture2);
        skullmouthopen.setPosition(300, 200);

        gameDisplay.draw(skullmouthclosed);
        gameDisplay.display();
        f();    
        gameDisplay.draw(skullmouthopen);
        gameDisplay.display();
        f();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're calling `loadFromFile` on the same texture twice. Also, that code should not be in the loop and you don't need two sprites. **Voted to close**.

Comment: And you're missing `gameDisplay.clear();` in case the images have transparent parts, or if you plan to be moving them later.

Answer (score 0):

For animations, you'll typically want some update counter or timer. Also – as mentioned in the comments – try to avoid (re-)loading or copying textures in your main loop as this will slow down everything.

You'd most likely want to try something like this:

```
// Create and load our textures and sprites
sf::Texture texOpen, texClosed;
texOpen.loadFromFile("mouthOpen.png");
texClosed.loadFromFile("mouthClosed.png");
sf::Sprite mouthOpen(texOpen);
sf::Sprite mouthClosed(texClosed);

// Timing related objects (see below)
sf::Clock clock;
sf::Time passedTime;

while(window.isOpen())
    // Event handling would happen here

    // Accumulate time
    passedTime += clock.restart();

    // Subtract multiples of two seconds (one animation cycle)
    while (passedTime > sf::seconds(2))
        passedTime -= sf::seconds(2);

    // Clear the window
    window.clear();

    // Decide what to draw based on the time in our interval
    if (passedTime <= sf::seconds(1))
        window.draw(mouthOpen);
    else
        window.draw(mouthClosed);

    // Display the window
    window.display();
}
```

Also note that depending on the size of the graphic you might want to have both textures/sprites/frames in one texture.

Comment: Thanks guys. I simply didn't know that you had to write the name of the texture twice! :)